# Dividir celda de un dataframe en varias filas manteniendo el resto de columnas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe llamado `EECH` de la siguiente forma.
Como se observa hay filas en cuya columna `name` tienen más de un dato.
[image: Imagen]

Requiero que quede un dato por fila y que conserve la misma información para las siguientes columnas así como el siguiente ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba trabajando el siguiente código; sin embargo, solo me funciona para dividir la columna en varias filas pero no le pone el mismo dato en `Estado` y `Tiempo` (le coloca uno que no sé de dónde sale).

```py
# Separo por espacio y creo una serie
EC=EECH['Name'].str.split(' ').apply(pd.Series,1).stack() 
# Alineamos índice al del dataframe original
EC.index=EC.index.droplevel(-1)
# Damos nombre a la serie
EC.name='Name' 
# Eliminamos columna name original
del EECH['Name']
# Unimos
EECH=EECH.join(EC)
```

Comment: Buen día, por favor agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` como texto, y el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema. Las imágenes no son de mucha ayuda y siempre deben de utilizarse como último recurso.

Answer (score 1):

Primero convertimos los valores múltiples de la columna en listas:

```py
EECH['Name'] = EECH['Name'].str.split(' ')
```

A continuación usamos el método [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), que nos dará el resultado esperado:

```
EECH = EECH.explode('Name')
```

Nótese que la función `explode` tiene un flag llamado `ignore_index`.
Por defecto este argumento vale `False`.
Eso significa que en el dataframe resultante mantendrá el índice del dataframe original.
Si se quiere tener unos índices *0, 1, ..., n-1*, escríbase `ignore_index=True`.